# Boquete to Panamá by bus on 3rd March

Tags: buses, panama, carnival-mardi-gras

I need to get from Boquete to Panama City (in Panama - not Florida!) on Sunday 3rd March 2019.  I have found a timetable [here](http://horariodebuses.com/EN/pa/) however with that weekend being the start of carnival I would like someone with local knowledge to confirm that buses will be running.  Will they be extremely crowded due to carnival?  Is it possible, or advisable to make a reservation in advance?

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, buses from Boquete to David and from David to Panama City maintain the usual daily timetable throughout the carnival, and it was not a problem to buy a ticket on the day.  In fact, tickets can only be bought on the day of travel.  The early morning local bus from Boquete to David was somewhat crowded with a few people standing in the aisle.  The long-distance bus from David to Panama City has assigned seats so even though most seats were occupied, it did not feel overly crowded.